# How to use is_split_into_words with Huggingface NER pipeline

Tags: transformer, named-entity-recognition, huggingface

I am using Huggingface transformers for NER, following this excellent guide: https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train.

My incoming text has already been split into words. When tokenizing during training/fine-tuning I can use `tokenizer(text,is_split_into_words=True)` to tokenize the incoming text. However, I can't figure out how to do the same in a `pipeline` for predictions.

For example, the following works (but requires incoming text to be a string):

```
s1 = "Here is a sentence"
p1 = pipeline("ner",model=model,tokenizer=tokenizer)
p1(s1)
```

But the following raises the following error: `Exception: Impossible to guess which tokenizer to use. Please provide a PreTrainedTokenizer class or a path/identifier to a pretrained tokenizer.`

```
s2 = "Here is a sentence".split()
toks = tokenizer(s2,is_split_into_words=True)
p2 = pipeline("ner",model=model)
p2(toks)
```

I don't want to join the incoming text into one sentence because whitespace is significant in my use case. Post-processing the outputs of the pipeline will be complicated if I just pass in one string rather than a list of words.

Any advice on how I can use `is_split_into_words=True` functionality in the pipeline?

Comment: Did you ever find out and could provide the answer?

Comment: Sadly not @MauriceSchleußinger - for now I'm just converting the list of tokens back into a string with `" ".join(foo)` which style is giving me good enough results in my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

evalute.evaluator.token_classification.py has this line:

```
        data = data.map(lambda x: {input_column: join_by.join(x[input_column])})
```

So even though the HuggingFace evaluator takes as input text that is carefully split into tokens for token classification tasks, to actually generate a model prediction, under the covers it is just doing the same trick to turn a list of tokens into a single text string input for the NER pipeline:

`" ".join(alist)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not set on this particular model for NER, there are some that work with multi-sentence texts straight away without any manual splitting:

- https://huggingface.co/flair/ner-english
- https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities-101